# Как добиться перебора массивов np.array для каждого спикера?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, комбинаторика

Задача перебрать всякий массив np.array() внутри каждой папки `spk`. Мне надо, чтобы np.array() создали кортежи по 2 элемента-массива в каждом. Причем нужны все варианты сочетаний массивов, но только внутри каждой папки `spk` по отдельности.

Итак, на входе словарь `speaker_wavs`:

```
{'spk1': [array([ 5.7989768e-05, -3.0932188e-05, -6.9003938e-05, ...,
          7.1993265e-05,  4.7599726e-05,  4.8396392e-05], dtype=float32),
  array([ 7.5168966e-04, -4.5251290e-05,  3.4856668e-04, ...,
         -2.5292889e-03, -2.9699195e-03, -2.6236360e-03], dtype=float32),
  array([-0.00094804, -0.00024563, -0.00010466, ...,  0.01256133,
          0.01113857,  0.00603152], dtype=float32),
  array([ 0.0007968 ,  0.00047213, -0.00070908, ..., -0.00846404,
         -0.00792614, -0.00820034], dtype=float32)],
 'spk10': [array([ 0.00150004,  0.00187945,  0.00227684, ..., -0.0005368 ,
         -0.00018098, -0.00036559], dtype=float32),
  array([-0.00133576, -0.00131788, -0.00158764, ...,  0.0017464 ,
          0.00235882,  0.00250746], dtype=float32)],...}
```

На выход требуется получить:

```
# для spk1 -> перебор по 2 элемента в кортеже всех array()
# для spk10 -> перебор по 2 элемента в кортеже всех array()
# и так для всех папок spk
```

Написал код, но как будто он дает иной результат. Насколько он ошибочный - папок 10, а списков перебора получилось 7:

```
from itertools import combinations

for elems in speaker_wavs.values():
  
  res = list(combinations(elems, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей
  print(res)
```

Comment: Чем вам не нравится результат? Приведите конкретный пример и укажите конкретную проблему.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, уточнил в вопросе: изначально папок 10, а списков перебора вышло 7

Comment: Поместите в цикл `print('UGU')` и сосчитайте количество `UGU` в выводе.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, 10 - видимо, часть списков не выведены в консоль. Не встречался с 'UGU'

Comment: Все итерации цикла на месте. Списки пар размещаются между `UGU`. Если вы недовольны конкретным списком, задайте новый вопрос.